# Перегрузка операторов. Передача по ссылке.

Tags: function-overloading, классы, c++

Доброго времени суток. При перегрузке оператора += передается const Logbook &rightLogbook.
Константа - понятна, но с какой целью передача идет по ссылке? Ибо если передавать само значение (без &, просто const Logbook rightLogbook), то программа работает так же. Значение "правого" операнда все равно не будет изменяться. Много где находил, что идет передача по ссылке, но почему - не понятно :C.

```
  class Logbook {
    private:
    int logMonth, // Month covered by logbook
        logYear, // Year for this logbook
        entries[31]; // Logbook entries

void Logbook::operator+=(const Logbook &rightLogbook)
    {
    for(int i=1;i<=getDaysInMonth(); i++)
     {
     entries[i]=entries[i]+rightLogbook.entries[i];
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эффективность.

Представьте себе, что вы передаёте объект огромного размера по значению. При этом вызовется конструктор копирования, и практически впустую скопирует объект, который по окончанию процедуры будет просто выкинут за ненужностью.

Передача по ссылке позволяет этого избежать.

Answer (score 0):

Безопасность.

Пример: объект имеет переменные с динамически получаемой памятью, и деструктор, который при уничтожении объекта освобождает эту память. При передаче в функцию по значению в новый локальный объект функции копируются все значения переменных передаваемого объекта, в том числе адреса памяти, на которые указывают "динамические" переменные. Когда функция закончит работу, локальный объект удалится, и сработает его деструктор - динамически выделяемая память будет высвобождена. Получается, что некоторые переменные исходного объекта будут указывать на уже освобожденную память. Это может привести к ошибкам.

А что будет, если в ходе работы программы в освобожденную память будет записано значение какой-либо другой переменной, а исходный объект вдруг будет удален? - Сработает его деструктор...

Comment: Не-не, отсутствие правильного конструктора копирования само по себе жирный баг.